# ARCamera Issue when migrating to Qualcomm Augmented Reality vuforia-unity-android-ios-3-0-6

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

FYI: I am using unity4.5.1f3 pro free version as of now.

My app is using ARCamera and I have migrated unity project for "vuforia-unity-android-ios-3-0-6 by following steps mentioned over here : [[https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/migrating-your-unity-project]](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/migrating-your-unity-project%5d)

After that I am receiving an error as below:

Type `DefaultTrackableEventHandler' does not contain a definition for`ar_detected' and no extension method `ar_detected' of type`DefaultTrackableEventHandler' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In older version there is a bool flag of "ar_detected" in DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs located at plugin path : Qualcomm Augmented Reality/Scripts/DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs and in new version vuforia-unity-android-ios-3-0-6 this flag is not available, I am getting stucked with this change to identify what change will I required to do in my C# script,

Is there any other dependency I have missed when migrating to new version of Qualcomm Augmented Reality?
any one who can guide me on this?

Thanks,

Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for migration issue of Qualcomm Augmented Reality for vuforia-unity-android-ios-3-0-6 version,

Actually when older version is there other developer makes some change inside the DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs to get ride for Augmented Reality for Camera feature,

I did same changes with new DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs and got no error and it working fine now :)